# Connect multiple AD domains to multiple AD Domains in single Azure tenant

Tags: azure, entra-id

I have a requirement to replicate three domains to Azure, they are all different domain names, there is a two way trust between the domains, I’m trying to work out how to use AD connect to replicate the domains to azure, do I need to add a custom domain for each domain and replicate to Azure AD or do I create iaas domain controllers and stretch ad into azure?

Comment: Are these domains in the same forest?